# Deleted poetry cache folder and cannot put things back

Tags: python-poetry

How to recreate the poetry cache folder, since I deleted it creating it again not helping. Now I've set the venv inside the project folder.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the question is. You probably should provide a lot more details, for example which commands you have run, what were the results, why are these results not what you wanted, and what results you expected.